# Waiting for a virtualbox automated guest login to complete

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, automation, automatic-logon

Is there way to tell if an [automated logon](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#autologon_win) to a virtualbox windows guest has completed?

I'm currently using virtualbox machines as part of a test process on windows, but at the moment I have to manually wait for login to complete. Is there a way to script this? Perhaps a command I could use in association with `VBoxManage guestcontrol`?

Comment: Are you certain you need "automated logon"? I am currently using 'vboxmanage guestcontrol' to execute code on guest as part of my own test process. I am simply manually waiting time for the guestcontrol logon to complete until my automated tests execute. although: this may not work for you if a desktop dession / gui is required for your test suites.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you suggested, this is a problem because it does relate to GUI testing

Answer (score 3):

Note: I haven't tried this myself.

Could you not have a logon script in the guest that does `VBoxControl guestproperty set LogonCompleted true` and then do `VBoxManage guestproperty MyVM wait LogonCompleted` on the host to detect when this has run?